# ativar teclado do celular, logo quando a página é carregada

Tags: html5, jquery-mobile

Já coloquei o atributo autofocus no input, ai quando a página carrega o focu está no input, mas só que o teclado do celular não está ativando..

```
<input type="search" name="password" id="search" value="" placeholder="Buscar" autofocus>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente: `<input type="email" name="email">`

Segue mais explicação: http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-html-css-javascript/bootstrap-e-formularios-html5/